# nginx-ingress wont listen on different port number

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am deploying an nginx ingress controller via helm3.  I am using the following values.yaml (Which specifically says to use port 81), but after I deploy it The controller still says it is listening on port 80.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```shellsession
$ helm upgrade --install --namespace=default -f values.devops.yaml nic-default stable/nginx-ingress
$ kubectl get svc nic-default-nginx-ingress
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                      AGE
nic-default-nginx-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.100.36.39   somedomain.com  80:30193/TCP,443:30265/TCP   7h53m
```

values.yaml

```yaml
clusterName        : dev
region             : us-east-1
tag                : v1.0.0

revisionHistoryLimit: 3
rbac:
    create: true
defaultBackend:
    enabled: false
serviceAccount:
    create: false
    name  : "nginx-ingress-default"
controller:
    kind                 : "Deployment"
    name                 : "controller"
    ingressClass         : "nginx-default-internal"
    replicaCount         : 1
    minAvailable         : 1
    minReadySeconds      : 5
    hostNetwork          : false
    extraArgs            :
        http: 81
    image:
        tag       : "0.30.0"
        pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    config:
        keep-alive                   : "600"
        upstream-keepalive-timeout   : "600"
        enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
        ssl-redirect                 : "false"
        force-ssl-redirect           : "false"
        use-forwarded-headers        : "true"  # https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1957#issuecomment-462826897
    nodeSelector:
        namespace: default
    publishService:
      enabled: true
    containerPort:
        http: 81
    service:
        type       : "LoadBalancer"
        enableHttp : true
        enableHttps: false
        ports:
            http: 81
        targetPorts:
            http: 81
        annotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal                : 0.0.0.0/0
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol        : http
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout : "500"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol          : "*"
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: "Cluster=dev,Type=k8s,Namespace=default"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to install nginx ingress controller on a new eks cluster using the below command and its load balancer service got port 81:

```
 helm upgrade --install --namespace=default  nic-default stable/nginx-ingress --set 'controller.service.ports.http=81'

kubectl get svc | grep controller
nic-default-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.100.9.106   81:31023/TCP,443:31864/TCP   27m
```

Not sure what's the problem on your side.

Note that this chart is deprecated. Use  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx instead.